# Use Spread operator for arguments in an Angular pipe

Tags: angular

I have a pipe which takes multiple argumenst:

```js
export declare class FooPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(defaultValue: string, key: string, ...replacements: string[]): Observable<string>;
    static ɵfac: ɵngcc0.ɵɵFactoryDef<FooPipe>;
    static ɵpipe: ɵngcc0.ɵɵPipeDefWithMeta<FooPipe, "fo">;
}
```

It's used like this:

```html
{{'bla' | foo:'bar':'blarg':'glub':'blub'}}
```

while `blarg` and the following are optional.

What if I have all those arguments for the `replacements`-argument in an array?
Apparently I can not do:

```html
{{'bla' | foo:'bar':...replacements}}
```

Is there a way to use the spread operator inside this pipe syntax or do I have write a function, instantiating the pipe and so on?

Comment: Why not to use array directly?

Comment: The Pipe's syntax is not in a scope I could change.